# An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on a system just to get it up and running

```
Ruby 1.8.7 
Ubuntu server 12.04
```

Its an old system and I am trying to get it running just so I can start updating it. The problem is whenever I run

```
$ bundle install
```

It gives me this error.

```
An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

I need to install libxml-ruby (1.1.3), via my gemfile. However, I am not sure how else to get around this issue. I am a novice at the whole process with ruby and eager to learn. This one just stumps me.

Comment: Is `libxml` installed? Try `sudo apt-get install libxml`.

Comment: I will get around to trying that, however I think I did that before. Would it have anything to do with Ubuntu version?

Comment: I’ve installed Rails on Ubuntu 12.04 several times, so it shouldn’t be that.

Comment: Alright so I found out that it has to be on Ubuntu 10.04.
`An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install libxml-ruby -v '1.1.3' succeeds before bundling.`

Comment: Also, cannot find `libxml` when trying to install.

Comment: Try `libxml2` instead.

Comment: I used this, and I think this worked `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev`

Comment: Only `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`. Because there are a lot of different libmx versions.